# Раздельная компиляция error C2182

Tags: c++

аheader.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef test_H_
#define test_H_

void test(string& vr);

#endif
```

test_f.cpp

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

void test(string& vr){

    vr = "123";
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string vr;
    test(vr);
    cout << vr;
    cout << "pause..." << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>test.cpp
1>C:\test\test\header.h(6,6): error C2182: 'test': this use of 'void' is not valid
1>C:\test\test\header.h(6,11): error C2065: 'string': undeclared identifier
1>C:\test\test\header.h(6,19): error C2065: 'vr': undeclared identifier
1>C:\test\test\test.cpp(9,5): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Подскажите что делаю не так?

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос, нажав ссылку "Править"

Comment: `#include <cstring>` -> `#include <string>`. И лучше это сделать прямо в заголовочном файле.

Comment: Не помогло добавил. ( Добавил в заголовочный даже. Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>test.cpp
1>C:\test\test\header.h(8,12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\test\test\header.h(8,8): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'test'
1>C:\test\test\test.cpp(10,12): error C2872: 'string': ambiguous symbol
1>C:\test\test\header.h(8,1): message : could be 'int string'

Comment: Вопрос решен!  1. В header.h добавить: using namespace std; 2. В  test_f.cpp <cstring> заменить на <string>. После этого всё заработало. Всем спасибо.